# openssl: ca key too small but key size is 4096

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, bitbucket-pipelines

I am getting a weird error when try to upload a zip to an external API. The error is "ca key too small".

I have already verified and my p12(key + certificate) is generated with SHA256 signature and the key size is 4096 bytes.
In order to verify this, I added my p12 file to OSX keychain.
I checked the certificate it says `Signature Algorithm` as `SHA-256 with RSA Encryption` and Public key size as `4.096 bits`. I checked the private key it says `RSA, 4096-bit`. I already tried generating a new p12 key pair but the issue persists.

I am facing this issue when deploying a zipped package through bitbucket pipelines. We recently switched our node version from 14.XX to 16.XX and because of this we started facing this issue.

Upon deeper investigation it seems that the "openssl.cnf" packaged as part of node 16.XX docker image has `SECLEVEL` specified with value `2`. If I downgrade the node version to 14.XX and inspect the "openssl.cnf", it is missing the `SECLEVEL` entry altogether. So, for node image 16.XX, if I modify the SECLEVEL to 1 by manipulating the "openssl.cnf" everything works fine.

```
# node 16.XX docker image /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=2
```

I am also able to replicate the same issue locally by add the SECLEVEL in my local "openssl.cnf" file and then making the API call to the server. Below is the stripped down version of the nodejs code.

I do not want to use this hack of downgrading the SECLEVEL as I would like to understand what exactly the issue is. As per my understanding, my key size(4096) is not small.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var endpoint = 'SOME_ENDPOINT";
var instance = "SOME_INSTANCE"
var file = './test.zip';
const options = {
    pfx: '/path/to/certificate.p12',
    passphrase: 'SOME_PASSPHRASE',
}
var token = 'SOME_TOKEN';
var opts = {
    baseUrl: 'https://' + instance,
    uri: endpoint,
    auth: {
        bearer: ( token ? token : null )
    },
    strictSSL: true,
    method: 'PUT'
};

if (options && options.pfx && fs.existsSync(options.pfx)) {
    var stat = fs.statSync(options.pfx);
    if (stat.isFile()) {
        opts.agentOptions = {
            pfx: fs.readFileSync(options.pfx),
            passphrase: options.passphrase // as passphrase is optional, it can be undefined here
        };
    }
}

var req = request(opts, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(req);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what in your key store. But the error message does not refer to the key size of the certificate but to the key size of the ca, i.e. the issuer of the certificate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Thanks for the reply. It makes sense to me. I have asked the team responsible to check this. Hopefully, this is the issue :)